# links in pop up window in fusion-chart

Tags: asp.net, charts, fusioncharts

i am pulling the data from a database in order to populate my chart but i am not sure how to control the size of the window.  Here is my code:

```
strXML.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["Category"].ToString(), reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("P-ChildDrill.aspx?AvgDays=" + reader["Category"].ToString()));
```

I have seen some example where they have used this kind of syntax but i can't seem to figure out how to apply it on my code:
here is the example i saw:

```
link='P-detailsPopUp,width=400,height=300
```

My question is how can take this example and apply it in my code?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the width/height of the pop up window,you would need to start the link with prefix "p-" and would need to pass the name of the window followed by the window parameters separated by commas.

```
strXML.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["Category"].ToString(), reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("P-detailsWin,width=400,height=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no-ChildDrill.aspx?AvgDays=" + reader["Category"].ToString()));
```

The list of possible attributes that can be passed are listed in the below link:

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DrillDown/PopUps.html